# DateTime format not proper

Tags: c#, datetime-format

i am trying to format the date to this format. 01/20/2013 02:30PM EDT, using this

`LastModified.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mmtt");`

but the result is coming like this

`01-20-2013 02:30PM` dont know why it is showing `'-'` instead `'/'`.

Also, for **timezome**, it seems there is only format available like `+02:00`. But I want timezone as string, i could not find any format for this, how can I get is as string like **EDT/PST/IST** etc?

Comment: Try specifying the culture

Comment: For which culture are you formatting your DateTime? I ask this, because the Indian culture uses `-` by default.

Comment: @MartinMulder i have not specified the culture for formatting, but yes, I guess its the reason, the device culture is Indian.

Comment: just so you know, 05/02/2013 is the 5th of **february** 2013 ... God damn americans... ;-)

Comment: @MartinMulder but tell me one thing, is i use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, formatting will remain unaffected despite the change in culture. m i right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the MSDN page on [custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which is used to differentiate years, months, and days. The appropriate localized date separator is retrieved from the DateTimeFormatInfoDateSeparator property of the current or specified culture.

If you want it to definitely use `/`, you should *either* use the invariant culture, *or* quote the slash (`"MM'/'dd'/'yyyy hh':'mmtt"`). Note that I've quoted the time separator as well, as that can vary by culture too. I've also changed it to use the 12 hour clock, as per Arshad's answer.

When using a custom date/time format, you should probably use the invariant culture anyway. (For example, it seems odd to use a UK culture to format the string in a US-centric way - today would normally be represented as 02/05/2013 in the UK, not 05/02/2013.)

In terms of a time zone specifier - I don't know any way to use the time zone abbrevation within date/time formatting. I would personally advise *against* using abbreviations anyway, as they can be ambiguous and confusing. I can't see anything within `TimeZoneInfo` which even exposes that information for you to manually add it.

(It's possible that in [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) we'll support *formatting* with the abbreviation, but probably not *parsing*, precisely because of the ambiguity.)

Comment: how can i use culture invariant here?

Comment: @ay89: By specifying the culture in the `ToString` call. Look at the overloads for `ToString` for more details.

Comment: Like that: `yourDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mmtt",invcul);` where invcul is `CultureInfo invcul = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Quoting the slashes should be done thus: `LastModified.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy HH':'mmtt")` I'd also quote the ':' (just to be sure)

Answer (score 2):

i have found one mistake is that ,`HH` means time in 24 HRS format. You can try

```
string date = "01/20/2013 02:30PM";
DateTime dtTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dtTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dtTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatting of DateTime is influenced by your Culture and your format string. Your current culture (`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`) uses the `-` as the default seperator of your date components.

The Culture of India uses `-` and since you are from Inda, it would make sence (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_India)

Two options:

1. Choose a correct Culture which uses the `/` by default as seperator. For example: `LastModified.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mmtt", new CultureInfo("en-US"));`
2. Or reformat your format string with the escape character `\`. For example: For example: `LastModified.ToString("MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mmtt");`

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx